# Unable to match starting character in a word using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a coupon code which dynamically generates with provided `prefix`, `suffix` and `length`

I have generated one coupon code with following param :

> ```
> prefix  - NOV
> Suffix  - OFF
> Length  - 10
> ```

And coupon `NOVQ3QVOFF` generated. I have to validate where it generated with given prefix and suffix. for that I'm using below code:

```
String couponCode = "NOVQ3QVOFF";
String pattern = "^NOV*";
System.out.println(Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(couponCode).matches());
```

But getting output as `false`

Also tried `pattern = "^NOV";` but no success. Also i have validated regex online its matching there.

[image]

Can someone please help. whats wrong here ?

Comment: `matches` requires a full string match. Use `find` to get partial matches. Note: `^NOV*` matches `NO` at the start of string and then 0 or more `V`. You probably wanted `^NOV.*` or even `^NOV.*OFF$`, in `matches`, you may omit the anchors and use `s.matches("NOV.*OFF")` or replace `*` with the limiting quantifier that will match a specified number of occurrences of any char, say, `.{6}` will match any 6 chars other than line break chars.

Comment: You most likely need `NOV.*` or even `NOV.{4}OFF`

Comment: Try this [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xSNych/1)

Comment: @SebastianProske, Thanks you suggestion is helpful